# Heroku shows blank page, works in local version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

ONLINE Heroku logs:

```
Started GET "/" for 180.246.231.210 at Tue Jan 25 08:25:43 -0800 2011
  Processing by Store::HomeController#index as HTML
  Country Load (7.6ms)  SELECT "countries".* FROM "countries" WHERE ("countries"."id" IS NULL) LIMIT 1
  Country Load (1.9ms)  SELECT "countries".* FROM "countries" LIMIT 1
  SQL (2.5ms)   SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
 WHERE a.attrelid = '"zones"'::regclass
 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
 ORDER BY a.attnum
Completed   in 15ms
```

LOCAL production logs:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-01-26 08:10:21 +0700
  Processing by Store::HomeController#index as HTML
  LeftSidebarLink Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "links".* FROM "links" WHERE ("links"."type" = 'LeftSidebarLink') AND ("links"."target_url" = 'http://localhost:3000/') ORDER BY position LIMIT 1
  LeftSidebarLink Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "links".* FROM "links" WHERE ("links"."type" = 'LeftSidebarLink') AND ("links"."target_url" IN ('/')) ORDER BY position LIMIT 1
  LeftSidebarLink Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "links".* FROM "links" WHERE ("links"."type" = 'LeftSidebarLink') AND ("links"."target_url" IN ('')) ORDER BY position LIMIT 1
1
2
3
  FeaturedBanner Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "featured_banners".* FROM "featured_banners" WHERE (active = '1' OR (date_start >= DATE('2011-01-26') AND DATE('2011-01-26') <= date_end))
  Image Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "images".* FROM "images" WHERE ("images"."id" = 4) LIMIT 1
  FooterLink Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "links".* FROM "links" WHERE ("links"."type" = 'FooterLink') AND ("links"."parent_id" IS NULL) ORDER BY position
Rendered store/home/index.html.erb within layouts/store_default (13.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 175ms (Views: 63.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
```

Note: That 1, 2, 3 lines were output of logger.debug.

How come two EXACTLY same setup and set of files and database shows different output?? Why is it somehow store/home/index.html.erb not getting loaded in my online application?

Comment: Are you sure you're running the same code both in Heroku and locally? It looks like you're running different version of the code. Maybe you haven't pushed the code to Heroku?

Comment: Nope, both are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a thought: Have you actually included the data into the database on Heroku? (i.e. Seed the database)

Comment: This issue does not happen again, maybe due to latest heroku update